# Where are the Tiny Death Star files located on Windows Surface RT?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star, windows-rt

I had worked up to 74 levels on Tiny Death Star, but I opened it up yesterday and it was back to square one, everything gone.

I reinstalled and now want to backup the data files. Where are they located?